# Xact vs AudioContent

Tags: c#, audio, xna, xact

I am using XNA to develop a game which requires both sound effects and music. I'm trying to figure out how to implement the sound engine. Microsoft provides the ability to use the Content Pipeline to load and play audio. However, I also seen people use Xact to do the same thing. My question is, whats the difference and what would be the better approach to making a sound engine?

Comment: It really depends on what you are building. You are not really (or at least shouldn't be) building a "sound engine" because that's what XACT and the Content Pipeline's audio stuff already are. Personally I recommend going with the easier Content Pipeline, and switching to XACT if you later find that you need it.

Comment: I am in a group and my responsibility is Engine programming. I am simply writing a wrapper class so that I can A) Provide ease of use and B) Have the ability to have multiple sound engines. I just wanted to know the pros/cons and figure out if MS intended for me to use the Content Pipeline or if everything could be done in Xact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xact is feature rich but complex to use. It was originally the only way to play sound but people wanted something simpler so Microsoft added the content pipeline method.

**Use the Content Pipeline if you want:**

- To play a sound (2d or 3d)
- To not have to invest a lot of time
  learning an audio framework

**Use Xact if you want:**

- Categories of sounds that can be
  interdependently controlled, like
  mute game sounds but not menu sounds
- Real time advanced control over sound
  pitch, volume.  For things like
  turrets spinning up, cars
  accelerating etc.
- To have multiple varieties of a
  single sound effect like a seven
  different pain sounds and have Xact
  choose which one to play.
- To have a sound play with slightly
  different pitch, volume, filter or 3d
  pan every time it is played.  This is
  really good for bullets and
  repetitive things like that.  There
  is nothing that says fake computer
  simulation like a repeating sound
  with no variance.
- To allow a game designer or sound
  designer full control to edit and
  change sounds without touching the
  code.
- To have sound banks (collections of
  sound) that you can load or unload as
  a group, which can use different
  compression settings and can be in
  memory or streaming.
- To mix the volume, pitch and priority
  of sounds in an editor.
- To apply filtering to a sound.
- To control whether the sound is
  looping or not.
- To use DSP Effects

One of my favourite things about Xact is editing and previewing of sound functions in editor.  For example a volume fade on a turret overheat sound.  With XACT you can sit down with the sound designer, even if he's not a technical guy and edit the control curves until he's happy with the sound.  Once you've set it up it's really easy to change later on.  In this example image here a turret is overheated.  At the end of the overheat cycle the hissing steam noise volume is reduced, but because it's a curve I have a lot of control over how the sound fades out.  I've used this with a beam weapon as well, dropping the frequency according to a curve as it runs out of ammo.